# Save Google Chart image to file

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm using the Google Charts API to generate some charts and am using an ajax request to send that data to an endpoint that will save the image to disk for use in a PDF. However, I'm not sure how to get the image string into a PHP image resource.

It looks something like this (I'll snip a bunch of the code to save some room):

```
<?php

$data = '{"image_data":"data:image/png;base64,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"}';

$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
$resource = imagecreatefromstring($decoded['image_data']);

var_dump($resource);
```

This throws a warning at the `imagecreatefromstring` step: `Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format`.

What's the right handler for that image format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your need to get rid of leading `data:image/png;base64,`
Also your base64 string looks corrupted . I did the following

```
<?php
$data = '{"image_data":"data:image/png;base64,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"}';
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);

$final = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $decoded['image_data']));
$im = imagecreatefromstring($final);
           if ($im !== false) {
              ob_clean();
              header('Content-type: image/png');
              imagesavealpha($im, true);
              imagepng($im);
              imagedestroy($im);
        }


?>
```

working fiddle
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7u1t-yfbe

Comment: @user101289 happy to help you